# Why are coriander plants dying?

Tags: plant-health, germination, transplanting, apples, pollination

I have lovely coriander in my window sill. After they grew really big, the stem began withering while the bushy coriander became brown. Is it because they reached seeding stage? How can I germinate so they grow seeds?

You might see a Apple plant. It was experimental seed which I sow and it grew up. Also wondering when to take it out and plant outside?

[image]

[image: coriander and Apple plant]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the coriander plant yes, it has reached its age since its been flowering and if they go pollinated then you should see the seeds growing. The seeds grow as a small ball then it dies like the rest of the plant you see here.

I would say due to the weather and the growing conditions it grew fast and went straight to flowering. This can happen for different reasons. Coriander grows bigger, bushier and you see more of the herbs part that can be used for eating or seasoning.

You still have flowers in there so they need to be pollinated so the seeds grow then you can use the seeds to germinate more.

Comment: Thanks. Does pollination happens on windows sill or do I need to shake the flower for it to drop seeds? What’s the best way

Comment: you will need to at least grab the flowers and stick them together so the pollen from each plants reaches each other. Usually outside this is done by bees or other bugs. You can try to rub the flowers together since they are long stems.

Comment: Coriander is not self pollinating, or not much. You want to make sure it is a flower from one plant on a flower from another plant. Also, you can probably google for how to tell a male from female flower. Outdoors it would have honey bees visiting multiple flowers. Maybe you can use a soft paint brush to transfer pollen.

Comment: I cannot make out if the flower is male or female, I google for it thanks, but they r so small and with my eyesight, it is like finding needle in haystack.